# How does Charisma affect your negotiation skills?

Tags: fallout-4

Obviously, higher Charisma means more success in conversation dialogues requiring a Charisma check. But exactly how much of an effect does each point have? How does this work against the difficulty levels of each check? Is there an upper limit for this effect?

After having some negotiation issues (pretty much 100% failure, since I usually treat Charisma as a "dump stat") in my first partial play-through, I actually scrapped the game and rolled a new character with 10 Charisma from the start. (My new logic being that Charisma checks are pretty much the *only* category of things that you'll nearly always have *only one* shot, at and can't usually work around it with just patience or player skill.) This character hasn't failed a Charisma check yet. She pretty much, literally, *always* gets her way.

So, I'm thinking CHA 10 means 100% success on Charisma checks of every difficulty. But I'm not sure. And I also would like to know how checks work at lower levels.

There appear to be three basic "levels" of Charisma checks, as indicated by their color in dialogue menus. In order of increasing difficulty, they are:

- Yellow
- Orange
- Red

So my question, broken down into basics is:

- Does CHA 10 actually result in 100% success on all Charisma checks (with the possible exception of some rigged checks - no spoilers if these exist, please)?
- Is there a minimum Charisma level at which each class of Charisma check becomes automatically successful?
- At lower Charisma levels, do the higher-level checks auto-fail or is there still a chance of success? If the latter, how does each Charisma level affect your chances against each level of check?

Comment: I've had Charisma checks fail at 10 charisma. Can't recall which ones exactly, but it's happened. That's with Black Widow maxed out as well. I'm curious to see an answer with specifics myself.

Comment: @DCShannon Thanks for the input. I wonder if a higher level of CHA does offer guaranteed success, or if perhaps the ones you failed where just rigged.

Comment: @DCShannon Are you sure about failing Charisma checks with 10? My current playthrough started with max Charisma, and I've yet to fail a single check. Currently at the part just before Bunker Hill, with pretty much every sidequest I've found completed (except one or two that are bugged).

Comment: I'm pretty sure, but I don't have a record, and that was my first character, so I can't say when or where. Those red ones can be hard.

Comment: Did you have charisma boosts on beside your base 10 charisma?

Comment: @DCShannon Sometimes yes. A lot of times no. Really starting to think I should pick up the PC version so it's easier to mod & playtest this stuff.

Comment: Yeah, me too. Based on previous Bethesda games, I prefer playing on console, but this whole Arqade thing would be easier on PC. Probably get the next one on PC.

Comment: @DCShannon It's been so long, I'm beginning to wonder if I can even manage playing an FPS or flight sim with keyboard/mouse anymore. Might have to just hook up one of the Xbox controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Even yellow isn't 100% guaranteed at high charisma levels maybe at 10 but I have seen failures at 7. Basically it is similar to Fallout 3 they just don't show the percentages anymore. Even with 10 on occasion you will get failures, so the black widow/lady killer perk is still useful even if you have 10 charisma. Best thing to do when you go up against speech checks is equip some items that boost charisma, (keep a few with you) save the game before you attempt the speech check, and if necessary use some chems to boost the charisma even further. Remember you can get it over 10 with items and stuff so may as well use them. (Also if you already have 10 and you pick up a special raising bobble head it will raise it to perm 11)

Comment: Dude, your answers are good, but please use commas and other interpunction.